# java.net.UnknownHostException for all api call

Tags: java, spring, docker, unknown-host

I have a java web application (spring) running inside a docker.

After few days all the outgoing api calls start throwing UnknownHostException 
exception.

Just Restarting the docker solves the issue but then this again reoccurs after sometime.

Can you point it some direction where to look for the bug.

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: api.bankoncube.com
um-cube |       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
um-cube |       at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
um-cube |       at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
um-cube |       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
um-cube |       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:427)
um-cube |       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:88)
um-cube |       at org.apache.axis.components.net.JSSESocketFactory.create(JSSESocketFactory.java:92)
um-cube |       at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.getSocket(HTTPSender.java:191)
um-cube |       at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.writeToSocket(HTTPSender.java:404)
um-cube |       at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:138)
```

Following is the docker setup

```
um-cube :
environment:
  SERVICE_8080_NAME : 'um'
  SERVICE_NAME : 'um'
  SERVICE_TAGS : 'um-cube'
  DOCKER_HOST_ADDR : $DOCKER_HOST_IP 
container_name : um-cube
ports :
  - "8093:8085"
#    links :
#      - mysql-cube:mysql
volumes_from:
  - logs
volumes:
  - ./um-cube:/usr/src/myapp/config/
image : $DOCKER_REGISTERY/um:prd
mem_limit: 500MB
command : ["java", "-Xmx256m", "-jar", "ROOT.jar", "-Dcube.config.dir=/usr/src/myapp/config/"]
```

Comment: Memory issue ? I don't think so. Seams that at sometime the DNS is not working. If you let continue the program, it recovers from this error later ?

Comment: Nope. waited for about 6 7 hours didn't recover

Comment: So this docker is replicated in 2 servers(load balanced) both started raising same exception approximately at same time

Comment: Also during that period api.bankoncube.com host was able to receive calls from different sources. So i don't think dns resolution was a problem. It is specific to these dockers only

Comment: Check if you can do DNS lookups within those docker instances.